# How to download csv file from google adword planner tool using casperJS with PhantomJs

Tags: csv, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to download resulting Excel CSV file from google keyword planner tool. My script is in caserJS with PhantomJS. 
Main part of script is

casper.then(function() {

```
    this.click(x('//*[@id="gwt-debug-retrieve-download-content"]'));
    var url = 'https://storage.cloud.google.com/planner-download/';
    this.download(url, 'keyword planner.csv');  
    this.wait(82000);

 });
```

Now I am getting without result csv file. How can we download?